# Are changes in sub-collections are supposed to trigger onWrite function or not?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can Firebase functions be triggered by a change in `subcollections` when the function is listening to a top level document? If not, what does the first line in the wildcard examples of the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions) mean?

**What does this mean??? if a sub-collection changes would it trigger the function? 
But it doesn't seem to and somewhere else in the same page says that too.**

```
// Listen for changes in all documents and all sub-collections
```

...

```
exports.useWildcard = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}')
  .onWrite((event) => {
    // If we set `/users/marie` to {name: "marie"} then
    event.params.userId == "marie"
    // ... and ...
    event.data.data() == {name: "Marie"}
  });
```

**What is the intended behavior for Firestore and function triggers**?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the comment in the sample code is incorrect for the sample whose document wildcard is this:

```
'users/{userId}'
```

Note that in the text below that sample it says:

> If a document in users has subcollections, and a field in one of those
>   subcollections' documents is changed, the userId wildcard is **not**
>   triggered.

The sample below it with the following wildcards:

```
'users/{userId}/{messageCollectionId}/{messageId}'
```

will be triggered only when documents in any subcollection of documents in `users` are written (not the documents immediately within `users`).

Feel free to [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for documentation or sample that you've for to be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I thought something is off. Just wanted to make sure what is the intended behavior. I already sent a feedback on the documentation page. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Clear answer Doug!! So to listen any attributes change of value from users/$userID/anythingChanged/anythingChanged/etc... we just need to add wildcards on the depth of the object we want the listener to... great!
But then the event.data._data is only going to be the modified value from wildcard point? or how would it behave ? I mean to recover the objects...